# Python variable resolution in a threaded context

Tags: python, variables, concurrency, scope

I am writing a small Python script that makes heavy use of threads / multiple processes and I came across an interesting race condition that I cannot find an explanation for.
I have a background process that plays a song that the user can skip or that can end on it's own, in both these cases I need to fire a callback to say it has ended.

Below is a psuedo code sample demonstrating the problem :

```
import threading, subprocess

def play_song(song_name, callback) :
    stop_any_previous_songs()
    play_song_in_subprocess_then_call(callback)

def main(self) :
    while True :
        music_stopped = threading.Event()
        def play_callback() :
            # say that the song stopped
            music_stopped.set()

        #Assume that the thread is actually a daemon
        threading.Thread(target=play_song, \
                         args=(get_next_song(), play_callback)\
                         .start()
        while not music_stopped.is_set() and user_not_interrupted() :
            # Spin
            pass

        if music_stopped.is_set() :
            # End of song reached, play the next song
            continue
        else :
            # User input from some source
            process_user_input()
```

The problem is that when starting a new song after a previous song had played the `play_callback` would be called as a result of the `stop_any_previous_songs()` call. When called the `play_callback` would call `set` on the `music_stopped` Event for the next song.

So my question is when the `play_callback` function is called is it merely going to the enclosing scope and looking for an object with the name `music_stopped'? Or is the underlying cause something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    def play_callback() :
        # say that the song stopped
        music_stopped.set()
```

Python would lookup the value of bare names like `music_stopped` using the [LEGB rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules) (Locals, Extended, Globals, Builtins). Since `music_stopped` is not a local variable, Python would next look in the enclosing (lexical) scope. Indeed, it would find `music_stopped` defined in the enclosing scope of the `main` function. The value is looked up dynamically -- in other words, the value returned would be the value of `music_stopped` at the time when the bare name is looked up, i.e. when `play_callback` is being executed. That value of `music_stopped` need not be the value at the time when `play_callback` was defined.

However, to bind `music_stopped` to the value when `play_callback` was defined, you could make `music_stopped` a local variable with a default value:

```
def play_callback(music_stopped=music_stopped):
    # say that the song stopped
    music_stopped.set()
```

The default value is evaluated and bound to the local variable at the time when `play_callback` is defined.

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice concise description of the behaviour I was seeing.